# Mac OS M1 Monterey 12.4: wrong python library with "Port"

Tags: python, numpy, apple-m1, macports

I´ve got a new MacBook Pro with M1 chip and it seems as if not alle of the open source software is converted to arm64.

Nethertheless, I try to compile missing tools (like numpy) manuell from source, like in the good ole days. As I try to do it I have to install, deinstall a lot and one tool is "port" which is working except for one thing that it complains all the time about Libraries I don't use anymore (because some tools (like Eclipse) for example are not working with Python 3.10). Therefore I regressed to Python 3.9 but every time I want to install something with "port" (which it does), it complains about the "old" Python 3.10 libs. How could I get rid of this messages?

> Warning: Error parsing file
> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lxml/html/diff.cpython-310-darwin.so: Error opening or reading file

Comment: Seems the architecture of this loadable module (.so) is not `arm64` as required by M1. Verify the _architecture_ using [`file`](https://superuser.com/a/1722168/1064978).

Comment: Yes, it is x86 architecture because not all components are already arm64 compiled

Comment: What did you use to install the Python versions mentioned (3.9 and 3.10)? See also [Python for m1 Mac](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253047045), which one is first on `PATH` environment variable? What is the `build_arch` and `frameworks_dir` of your [MacPorts config](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/internals.configuration-files.html) ?

Comment: Or did you mean the Python module [`port`](https://pypi.org/project/port) (rather than _MacPorts_, the macOS package-manager) ?

Answer (score -1):

I was in a sort of "Dead-Lock" because versions, Libraries and executables were not consistent with Python, Eclipse, Python pip packages etc, because some packages weren't ported to amd64 until now. For example numpy and I tried to compile it from source which was possible but still not working.

Then I stumbled over a hint in a different problematic were Rosetta was recommended for that specific problem. (I´ve never worked with Rosetta because most applications were running)

So I duplicated the "terminal" Application and configured one for Rosetta, started and installed Python 3.10 in it with all new packages and startet all executables from that terminal.

After some fiddling Eclipse startet with Python and the packages which my application needed, like numpy.

(And in addition to that, it seems as if it very much faster than before)

Comment: Universal solution to emulate x86 on `arm64` with Rosetta. Maybe you can provide some links to "hint in a different problematic were Rosetta was recommended" or "configured one Terminal for Rosetta", so others could benefit from this great recipe.

Comment: I tried only snippets from different sites: First install Rosetta as Root: > softwareupdate --install-rosetta

Comment: Then follow the part of configure a copied terminal and configure it for Rosetta: https://www.courier.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-to-setup-your-apple-m1-for-development/

Comment: Then I made all the necessary installations for building/installing the python environment and on top of that install the needed pip packages for my project. It was some worked because I fiddled a lot in the system and had to bring it back to an stable point. But then, I´ve got Python 3.10 with all the needed packages, numpy was the one left, which I could install in the Rosetta environment without problems and ran my application which I developed in XQuartz...